# Prove the following statement: If $f$ is continuos, $f(3)>0$ and $f(4)>0$, then $f$ has no zeroes between $3$ and $4$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I was asked to prove the following statement in my exam:

> If $f$ is continuous, $f(3)>0$ and $f(4)>0$, then $f$ has no zeroes between $3$ and $4$.

I know that this statement is true according to one of the [corollaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) of the Intermediate value theorem.

But I have to prove this. Please explain how to prove this statement.

Comment: This is not true

Comment: This statement is clearly false.  Take $f(x)=(x-3.5)^2$ for example.

Comment: do you maybe mean $f(3) > 0$ and $f(4) < 0$, then $f$ has at least one zero between $3$ and $4$?

Comment: @lulu How come it is false? The signs of the values did not change.

Comment: @user3456032 No, I am clear with my question.

Comment: @kunjimamu then check the counter example by lulu...

Comment: You are obviously missing a piece of information (maybe f is monotonic?) as this is clearly not true.  Take a pencil and paper and draw the point (3,1) and (4,1).  Now draw a curve between them that crosses or touches  the x axis and then goes back up.  That's the graph of a continuous function that has a root between 3 and 4.  Or simply state f(x) = (x- 3.5)^2 has a root at x = 3.5.

Comment: My counterexample is extremely clear, is it not?  If you prefer, take $g(x)=(x-3.5)^2-.01$.  That has two zeroes in the interval (namely $x=3.4,3.6$), $g(3)=.24=g(4)$, and $g(3.5)<0$.

Comment: @lulu very good, thanks!

Comment: Of course it is false.  f(3) > 0 and f(4) > 0 but f in between can do anything it wants for all we know.  The intermedate value theorem says for every c betweeen f(3) and f(4) there is an f(x) = c.  but it DOESN'T say than *only* for c between f(3) and f(4) can there be f(x) = c.  In other words, if f(3) =2 and f(4) = 5 then there must be some f(x) = 3.7 somewhere.  It doesn't say that there *can't* be f(x) =-98 or f(x) =6789 both of those *could* be true, or (they might not be).  But for 2 < c < 5 there must be some f(x) = c.

Answer (score 0):

With $f(x)=(x-\frac{10}{3})^2$, which is continuous, your statement is not satisfied.

$f(3)=\frac{1}{9}>0,\; \; f(4)=\frac{4}{9}>0$ but

$$\frac{10}{3}\in (3,4)$$

and

$$f(\frac{10}{3})=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate value theorem says that for $f$ continuous, if $f(3) = a > 0$ and $f(4) = b > 0$ then for any value $c$ between $a$ and $b$ there is an $x$ between $3$ and $4$ so that $f(x) = c$.

But the intermediate value theorem says nothing about values *outside* the range of $a$ and $b$.  The function can very easily go from $a$, drop down to $0$, and then go back up to $b$.  The obvious example is $(x -3.5)^2$ but there are an infinite counter examples.  $\cos (2\pi x)$ for example will have two zeros.  Simply taking a pencil and drawing a curve from $(3,1)$ to $(3.5,0)$ to $(4,1)$ will do it.

So this isn't true.

But if you add the condition that the function is monotonic, it must be true.

Or if $f(3) > 0$ and $f(4) < 0$ then there *must* be at least one zero between $3$ and $4$.

Or if $f(3) > 0$ and there are no zeros between $3$ and $4$, then you can prove $f(4)> 0$

Maybe you were supposed to prove one of those.

Answer (score -1):

This is not true, as if both $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ are positive and $f$ is continuous on $[3,4]$, then there is not by necessity no zero.

Proof by contradiction:

Let $f(x)=(x-3.5)^2$.

$f$ is continuous on $[3, 4].$

$f(3)=f(4)=.25>0$

$f(3.5)=0$

∴ There is a constant $C=3.5$ such that $f(C)$ that satisfies $f(C)=0$, inside the interval $[3,4]$.

As you see, it is not necessarily true that there is no zero between $f(3)$ and $f(4).$

Comment: 1) this doesn't prove that there must not be a zero which is what the question asked-- just that there doesn't have to be a zero  and 2) this doesn't prove that the doesn't have to be a zero-- it's just an argument that you failed to prove there must be one.  Failing to prove something doesn't mean it isn't true.  It just means your argument was the wrong one.

Comment: I wasn't proving that there HAS to be a zero, I was showing an example of how the given statement was false. There are other cases that DO follow the statement in question, but it is not necessarily ALWAYS true like the IVT.

Comment: @fleablood, I don't get you, I don't get the downvoter of this answer, and I don't get those who, so far, upvoted the OP twice. This answer simply shows why the OP's statement is false - what more would you like?

Comment: My comment was in response to the first edition of this answer which has been edited since.  The first answer claimed i) the statement was true because there does not need to be a 0, which is a different statement than the OP.  And ii) claimed to prove there need not be a 0 because the IMV th.  doesn't prove there is one.  A failure to prove something by one method is not a proof that it is not true.

Comment: Yes, I did edit it.
Does it fit the answer now?

Comment: Yes, yes, it does.